# Несколько вопросов по SVN (и Netbeans): не могу понять как они должны вместе работать?

Tags: svn, netbeans

Добрый день уважаемые знатоки.
Вынужден спросить (за что заранее извиняюсь), потому что не смотря на документацию по svn и netbeans никак не могу въехать в основы.

Если без Netbeans:
Есть удаленный сервер с доступом по ftp и svn.
Когда я скачиваю сайт через ftp получается одно количество файлов, когда через svn - другое (меньшее).

**<s>Вопрос: скажите, это так и должно быть? Если так, то что тогда с ними делать, совмещать их заменой файлов?</s>** - видимо совмещать

**<s>Вопрос: скажите как правильно совмещать файлы слитые по ftp и из svn?</s>** - видимо перезаливать слиты из svn поверх слитых с ftp.

Сейчас я вообще работаю как-то криво, у меня отдельно на localhost тот же сайт, я меняю какой-то файл, потом сливаю свежую версию в локальную папку с svn, потом сравниваю их через через notepad++ или другую diff-программу, потом делаю commit. Но шкурой чую, что не так оно должно быть.

Если вместе с Netbeans:
Я думал с ним будет легче, но головной боли только увеличилось.
Когда я завожу новый проект, он скачивает его по фтп. Потом я перехожу к меню Группа - SVN - Получить, и должен выбрать папку.

**Вопрос: Мне выбирать папку с закачанным проектом netbeans и сливать файлы из /trunk туда? Или отдельно?**

Если я скачиваю в отдельную папку svn, то система предлагает мне создать проект на основе скачанного. Но проект то у меня уже есть, скачанный по фтп.

**Вопрос: Есть возможность как то потом соединить эти проекты: слитый по фтп и слитый по svn.**

need help! Заранее спасибо за любую инфу или ссылки.

---

Еще потерзал поиск и нашел [аналогичный вопрос](http://www.askdev.ru/question/847/NetBeans-IDE-6-5-1-SVN-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/) годичной давности, и хотя открыл для себя кое что новое, вопросы не решились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Когда я скачиваю сайт через ftp получается одно количество файлов, когда через svn - другое (меньшее).

Потому что некоторые файлы незакоммичены в репозиторий.

А следующие вопросы уже не совсем корректны. Когда вы по фтп скачаете файлы, то там не будет директорий .svn с необходимыми для работы с репозиторием данными. Поэтому советую установить TortoiseSVN, скачать с помошью него ваш проект, затем в нетбинсе установить плагин для работы с SVN (он там один всего, не помню название), и подключить в нетбинс ваш скачанный проект (как проект с существующими исходниками). После этого все будет работать на УРА, без всяких заморочек с транками и фтп.

P.S.: сам я пользуюсь git ;)

Comment: Условия ставлю не я. У заказчика не сервере - subversion.
В том то и проблема, что скачанный по svn проект не полон, а в соответствии с документацией, в него не включены конфигурационные файлы. Ну и еще куча мелочи не включена, без них сайт на локальной машине не крутится... Пошел я снова биться с netbeans.

Comment: Ну так скачайте недостающие файлы по фтп. Если они не добавлены в свн, то может быть по соображениям безопасности, или просто потому что конфиг менять нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас вот так и делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Я наверное скажу классическую вещь но - почитайте документацию к SVN.
Вот [офф сайт](http://subversion.apache.org/). А вот [книги](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). Я думаю там вы быстрее сможете найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Да спасибо, svn-book на ред-бине я читаю. Пока что помогает в общем целом, в понятиях.